# My fancybox is not closing when using $.fancybox.close();

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Below is an extreme example of my actual working code. So I am opening up fanxybox by passing in $.fancybox([jquery_object])

The fanxybox opens up but when I try to close it, it doesn't seem to close

It only closed if I open it as an iFrame link which I can't do in my real working code

I have tried using

parent.fancybox.close()
fn.fanxybox.close()

and non seems to be working.

Included in the link is the actual code I am using. Any help would be really appreciated

Thank you!

https://gist.github.com/eldan88/ee261573ae3dac640a59

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me if you remove the javascript files from massmessage.html.  In particular, I had to remove these two files:

```
<script src="../assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/fancyBox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
```

The problem is caused by the reloading of jquery.

Comment: Thanks  but I need the query there.. not the fancybox but just the jquery.. Anyway to do it with the jqeury being loaded?

Comment: Are you accessing massmessage.html other than through fancybox?

Comment: No. Only through massmessage.html

Comment: Then why can't you remove the script tags? Jquery is already included by the calling page.

Comment: Wow you are right man. It did work. Thanks a lot!! Just one question I am confused about... The massmessage.html is part of the fancybox.html document ??

Comment: fancybox.html is the page you're viewing.  When you click the "Open Fancy Box" button two things happen.  First, an ajax GET request is made to retrieve the content of the massmessage.html file.  The content is stored in a variable named `data`.  Then fancybox adds a `div` in the fancybox.html page that contains that content.  It actually strips out the html and body tags.  Since you're not viewing massmessage.html directly anywhere, you should remove everything that is not inside the body tag.  All you really want is the html content that you want to end up inside the fancybox div.

Comment: By the way, if you use the developer tool in your browser, you can watch as the div is added to the DOM when you click the button.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much for that explanation. Yes I have the developer tool bar I.. I will check it out.